# Is it possible to draw a sub image to a canvas witout creating a new Image

Tags: codenameone

I've been experimenting with some custom components lately and had some issues with resource allocation.
Like for example if I had a method like so:

```
void paintSubImage(Graphics g, int x, int y, int w, int h, Image img){
    g.drawImage(img.subImage(x,y, w, h), 0, 0);
}
```

In this case the call to subImage actually generates a new image.
Is there any way to step around this. I'm not afraid to directly access the RGB int array, but I'm not sure of the best way paint it to a Graphics context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would indeed be very inefficient. A "better" approach would be to set the clip on the graphics target and drawing so only the portion of the image you want will appear.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try